# MySQL Limit Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which retrieves a list of records and gets the latest stage for each record from another table.

`SELECT leads.lead_id AS id, leads.fields, leads.date, users.name AS introducer, (SELECT lead_stage_id FROM lead_stage_history WHERE lead_stage_history.lead_id=leads.lead_id ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 1) stage FROM leads, users WHERE leads.introducer_id=users.user_id AND leads.account_id=1 ORDER BY date DESC;`

I am looking to limit the value returned by the stage column?

I wanted to filter the list of records to only display records at a certain stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL by using the `having` clause:

```
SELECT leads.lead_id AS id, leads.fields, leads.date, users.name AS introducer,
       (SELECT lead_stage_id
        FROM lead_stage_history
        WHERE lead_stage_history.lead_id = leads.lead_id
        ORDER BY date_added DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ) stage
FROM leads join
     users
     on leads.introducer_id=users.user_id
WHERE leads.account_id=1
HAVING stage = 'XXX'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

In other databases, you wou

```
select t.*
from (SELECT leads.lead_id AS id, leads.fields, leads.date, users.name AS introducer,
             (SELECT lead_stage_id
              FROM lead_stage_history
              WHERE lead_stage_history.lead_id = leads.lead_id
              ORDER BY date_added DESC
              LIMIT 1
            ) stage
      FROM leads join
           users
           on leads.introducer_id=users.user_id
      WHERE leads.account_id = 1
     ) t
where stage = 'XXX'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```